# The float property and expanding the elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two div elements, each one has an id, `lineNumber` and `code`.
The `lineNumber` is extendable and the `code` has the `contenteditable` attribute.
Also, I have applied the `float` to the `lineNumber` element.
The problem is when putting the mouse cursor in the `code` element to write something I found that writing cursor nested with the `lineNumber` element.

[image]

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  padding: 0px;
}

#editor {
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#lineNumber {
  height: 98.7%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #555;
}

#code {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98.7%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border-right: 3px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222;
  outline: 0;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="editor">
    <!-- The next element is extendable (horizontally) //-->
    <div id="lineNumber"> 1 </div>
    <pre id="code" contenteditable="true"></pre>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `#code` rule, remove `width:100%` (i.e. let it be `auto` width) and add `overflow:auto` to make the #code element a Block Formatting Context. That will make the whole block start after the floated element rather than just its contained line boxes.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  padding: 0px;
}

#editor {
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#lineNumber {
  height: 98.7%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #555;
}

#code {
  height: 98.7%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border-right: 3px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222;
  outline: 0;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="editor">
    <!-- The next element is extendable (horizontally) //-->
    <div id="lineNumber"> 100 </div>
    <pre id="code" contenteditable="true"></pre>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I threw in a margin on the #code id. Seems to have fixed it.

Really cool project though, I like it.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  padding: 0px;
}

#editor {
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#lineNumber {
  height: 98.7%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #555;
}

#code {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98.7%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border-right: 3px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222;
  outline: 0;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="editor">
    <!-- The next element is extendable (horizontally) //-->
    <div id="lineNumber"> 1 </div>
    <pre id="code" contenteditable="true"></pre>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works as a workaround, can you explain the original behaviour, i.e. that the cursor jumps to the right when typing the first character, and then going to the correct position when you backspace? Edit: Oh, only in Mozilla. That's OK then.

Comment: Thank you. The `margin-left: 1em;` which you added to solve the problem, unfortunately, is not a practical solution because I said the lineNumber is extendable and when the line number increases for example 100, look at the [result](http://i.cubeupload.com/jyFWGl.jpg), the problem came back again.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `#code` is not *floated* while the element preceeding it (`#lineNumber`) *is* floated.

You can use a *table layout* by giving `display: table` to the `#editor` and `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: top` to the `#lineNumber` and `#code` - see demo below:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  padding: 0px;
}

#editor {
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: table; /*ADDED THIS*/
  vertical-align: top; /*ADDED THIS*/
}

#lineNumber {
  height: 98.7%;
  /*float: left;*/
  display: table-cell; /*ADDED THIS*/
  vertical-align: top; /*ADDED THIS*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #555;
}

#code {
  display: table-cell; /*ADDED THIS*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 98.7%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border-right: 3px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222;
  outline: 0;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="editor">
    <!-- The next element is extendable (horizontally) //-->
    <div id="lineNumber"> 1 </div>
    <pre id="code" contenteditable="true"></pre>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer, your solution works fine in the modern browsers but unfortunately, isn't compatible at least with internet explorer 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of your margin with some simple javascript. If this doesn't seem to work responsively you will need an eventlistener to watch for lineNumber as it resizes.

```
<script>
var width = document.getElementById('lineNumber').offsetWidth;

document.getElementById("code").style.margin = width + 'px';
</script>
```

**If you want it to wrap lines try this!**
Change your pre into a div element , and add

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

To the corresponding CSS.

Comment: This might be better if you want it to wrap instead of floating off the page

Comment: Thank you. Concerning `margin: 15px;` which you added to solve the problem is not a practical solution because I said the `lineNumber` is extendable and when the line number increases for example 100, look at the [result](http://i.cubeupload.com/jyFWGl.jpg), the problem came back again.